# Vtk multiple render interactions - interaction on layers

Tags: pyqt5, vtk, renderer

I am writing a code with VTK and PYQT5 to plot two different actors on two renders. The actors are correctly shown, my problem is that mouse interactions are only applied to layer(0) (I imagine default renderer). My code looks to something like this :

```
self.renderer1 = vtk.vtkRenderer()
self.renderer1.SetLayer(0)
self.renderer2 = vtk.vtkRenderer()
self.renderer2.SetLayer(1)


self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().SetNumberOfLayers(2)
self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.renderer1)
self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.renderer2)  
 

interactor.SetInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())
```

how find to find a solution where both renderers are activated by mouse interactions.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set the same camera on both renderers.

```
self.renderer2.SetActiveCamera(self.renderer1.GetActiveCamera())
```